# Only run this function once when the page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’m building this site for my first customer, and Iv’e aded an animation when the page load with the logo and a little gif,
the problem is that when i’m on a different page from the “accueil” page (home), and I want to go back on the “Accueil” page, the loading animation will run again…

Here is the site : http://www.enzo-ustariz.fr/

and here is the relative jquery snippet :

```
$(window).on(‘load’, function() {
// Animate loader off screen
$(".loader").show().delay(4000).fadeOut();
});
```

I’m searching a way to delete it after the fisrt load or something else if you can help me !

Comment: So only run it once, ever?  Or just once per person?  Or just once per session (however you want to define a session)?

Comment: Only run when the site is loading, then never again

Comment: "when the site is loading" so you mean the very first time ever and that is it?  Or if a person comes to the site, show it, then they leave and come back the next day, show it again?

Comment: You will need to store a flag as either a cookie or in localstorage. The flag will be checked each time the user visits the page and updated if its already ran.

Comment: I mean if he go to the "Contact" section and then click again on "Accueil" I don't want the animation to run again .

Comment: Your site seems a bit weirdly structured, if you ask me. You have 3 sections that are single page, and 2 that are standalone: one is html, the other is php. Your problem comes from the fact that you do an actual navigation between index and contact, for example, so the page will get reloaded every time. Would it be an option to make your site have the same single-page structure for all the sections?

Comment: @HanletEscaño I added some delay to be sure that the user see the logo animation ^_^

Comment: @Sorix Right my site is weirdly structured, i'll to your advice, I added .php a while ago but there isn't php anymore in this code ..

Comment: It sounds kind of like a session timeout.  I'd go with one of @MasterYoda 's suggestions.  Set a cookie when it runs and let it expire, or use local storage.

Comment: There is no way to add a delete after the first use ? Which completely delete this snippet ? I've tried @Hanlet solution, adding .remove() at the end but it dosnt work

Comment: You cannot completely remove the code because even if you do, once you reload the page, it will get the original file and reload your animation. Since you keep navigating between pages, all your code will keep getting reloaded. If you change contact and chantier to work the same as the rest of the sections, you will no longer have this issue. I would recommend doing so to improve user experience also, the site structure is not coherent. If you want to keep the structure as it is, your only options are cookie, sessions or localstorage, which seem a bit of a stretch for a site this simple.

Comment: @Sorix How can I change Chantiers and contact to work the same as the rest ? Since for chantiers and contact I have navigate between pages, and for the rest it's on the same page?

Comment: If you do not want to follow the same logique with these 2 sections as with the rest (the scroll down to navigate option), you can just place each of your pages (contact, chantier, index, etc...) in different containers on the same html page that you can show/hide each time you want to simulate the navigation to them. Does this help?

Comment: @Sorix It could be a nice solution, but I never simulate such navigation, it could work i'm on it

Comment: This might help : [tutorial for single page app - no framework](https://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/single-page-app-without-a-framework). You are mostly interested in the HTML and the createQueryHash function. The rest should be show/hide the right containers according to the menu item selected. Bon courage ;)

Comment: Thank's ;) @Sorix

Answer (score 0):

You can break your gif loader code functionality and the actual 'Accueil' homepage into two different pages.

So when there is a hard reset on the browser or when a user logs in for the first time then this gif would appear followed by a redirection to the 'Accueil' home page and while you are navigating within the app you can directly call 'Accueil' homepage.